# How can I email this shopping cart array?

Tags: php, arrays, email, session

I can't figure out how to email the entire shopping cart array. I tried using the print_r function, but I only get one item in the result.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<?php session_start(); ?>

<?php

if (!isset($_SESSION['cart']) || (count($_SESSION['cart']) == 0)) {
    echo '<p>Your shopping cart is empty, so <a href="L14O1_buy.php">get shopping</a>.</p>';
} else {
    echo '<table>
    <tr>
    <th>Product</th>
    <th>Cost</th>
    <th>Units</th>
    <th>Subtotal</th>
    </tr>';
    $total = 0;

    foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $item) {

    echo "<tr>
        <td>{$item['item']}</td>
        <td>\${$item['unitprice']}</td>
        <td>{$item['quantity']}</td>
        <td>$".($item['unitprice'] * $item['quantity'])."</td>
        </tr>";
        $total += ($item['unitprice'] * $item['quantity']);
    }
    echo '</table>';
    echo "<p>Grand total: \$$total</p>";
}
?>


<?php
$to      = 'blah@gmail.zzz';
$subject = 'the subject';
$body = print_r($item);
$headers = 'From: blah@gmail.zzz' . "\r\n" .
        'Reply-To: blah@gmail.zzz' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $body, $headers);
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only the last item is shown, because your `foreach ( $_SESSION['cart'] as $item ) ...` loop uses the `$item` variable. $item is re-assigned each loop. At the end of the loop, the last value remains.

Try `$body = print_r($_SESSION['cart'], true);` instead.

Comment: Thanks, Damien. That works perfectly. Just curious: Is there a way to copy the html formatting into the email?

Comment: Sure. Just add a `$body='';` at the top and replace your echo's with `$body .= "<previously echoed text>";` This will fill the body variable with all the content you would normally have echoed. At the bottom, do an `echo $body;` to send the html to the browser, and also use `$body` as your message body text.

Comment: Incase you are wondering .. `$body .= "<some string>"` means: append <some string> to the `$body` variable.

Comment: If this answer helped. Please accept it by clicking the checkmark left of the answer :) (only saying because you are a new user on stack..)

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I'm such a noob that I can't figure it out. Can you recommend a webpage that walks noobies through the process?

Comment: I'll do you one better. Here you go: https://www.dropbox.com/s/hzeuu8ncw2rl4gh/file1.php

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php

session_start(); 

$body = '';

if (!isset($_SESSION['cart']) || (count($_SESSION['cart']) == 0)) {
    echo '<p>Your shopping cart is empty, so <a href="L14O1_buy.php">get shopping</a>.</p>';
} else {
    echo '<table>
    <tr>
    <th>Product</th>
    <th>Cost</th>
    <th>Units</th>
    <th>Subtotal</th>
    </tr>';
    $total = 0;

    foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $item) {

    echo "<tr>
        <td>{$item['item']}</td>
        <td>\${$item['unitprice']}</td>
        <td>{$item['quantity']}</td>
        <td>$".($item['unitprice'] * $item['quantity'])."</td>
        </tr>";
        $total += ($item['unitprice'] * $item['quantity']);
        $body .= print_r($item, true)."\n";
    }
    echo '</table>';
    echo "<p>Grand total: \$$total</p>";
}

$to      = 'blah@gmail.zzz';
$subject = 'the subject';
$body = "<pre>{$body}</pre>";
$headers = 'From: blah@gmail.zzz' . "\r\n" .
        'Reply-To: blah@gmail.zzz' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $body, $headers);
```